# Why does debian and ubuntu default to runlevel 2?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, init

I never thought about this before, but I was wondering why they chose runlevel 2.  Every other distro and OS I've used default to runlevel 3 (with the exception of AIX which also defaults to runlevel 2).

Comment: I'm confused, I think you want to edit your question. "Every other distro and OS I've used default to runlevel 2"

Comment: You're right.  That was a typo.

Comment: Not an answer to the why but Debian does not differentiate between runlevels 2-5. And if i would have to guess 2 is just the lowest available number so they choose to go with it.

Comment: Funnily I stumbled upon this just today. In fact I use mainly ubuntu lts versions (12.04, 14.04 and 16.04). Starting from 16.04 the default runlevel for ubuntu seems to be 5, 12.04 and 14.04 defaulted to 2.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Debian distribution (and hence Ubuntu, which is derived from it) does not define any differences between runlevels 2-5 as a matter of [policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#s9.3.3.1). It is up to the local system administrator to make use of runlevels as they see fit.

Since there is no difference between runlevels 2-5, a default runlevel 2 was chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Most distributions imho default to runlevel 5 (RedHat, Fedora, SLES, OpenSuSE) - meaning login with runnung X11 and GUI. You have to specify otherwise, if you do not want a GUI.

But the definition of runlevels does not seem to be fixed.

I rember Solaris used runlevel 5 for poweroff, 0 for halt (without power off).

Comment: Where is the answer to he question?   And Ubuntu doesn't default to RL 5.

Comment: @Oskar Skog: Removed Ubuntu. This is the answer to the second part of the Q.